# Concatenar variáveis em Jquery para enviar ao php somente do registro selecionado

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um `loop` onde mostro ao usuário o resultado de uma consulta, cada consulta dessa tem `3 variáveis` que preciso enviar para o php, o que estou tentando fazer é enviar ao php as variáveis que correspondem ao botão clicado, vejam a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que tentei fazer estava enviando todas as variáveis do formulário, mas como é uma alteração de status eu preciso que seja enviado as variáveis somente do registro a ser alterado.

O que tenho de script:

```
$(function() {      
$("#frmBusca").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {

        var IdOrdem = $("#IdOrdem");
        var IdUnicoop = $("#IdUnicoop");
        var Data = $("#Data");

        data: "IdOrdem=IdOrdem&IdUnicoop=IdUnicoop&Data=Data";

        console.log(data);
        return false;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'pUpOrdemPagamento.php',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#msgOrdem").html('<div class="alert alert-info fade in"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i><strong>AVISO!</strong> Enviando...</div>');
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.codigo == "1") {
                    $("#msgOrdem").html('<div class="alert alert-success fade in"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i><strong>AVISO!</strong>' + response.mensagem  + '</div>');
                window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 3000);                       
                } else {
                    $("#msgOrdem").html('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i><strong>ATENÇÃO!</strong> ' + response.mensagem + '</div>');
                }
                $('#frmBusca').each (function(){
                    this.reset();
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
                $("#msgOrdem").html('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in"><button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><i class="fa-fw fa fa-times"></i><strong>ATENÇÃO!</strong> Ocorreu um erro ao tentar enviar a pergunta. Contate o suporte técnico.</div>');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

A minha tabela está dentro de um foreach e está assim e os campos e formulário estão em inputs hidden.

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="161"><strong>Produto</strong></td>
          <td><?php echo $Retorno->Produto; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Safra</strong></td>
          <td><?php echo $Retorno->Safra; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Peso</strong></td>
          <td><?php echo $Retorno->Peso; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Valor</strong></td>
          <td><?php echo $Retorno->Valor; ?></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <?php if ( $Financiamento == 1 ) { ?>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><strong>Financiamento</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Banco</strong></td>
          <td align="left"><?php echo $Retorno->BancoFinanciamento; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Observação</strong></td>
          <td align="left"><?php echo $Retorno->Observacao; ?></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if ( $OrdemDeposito == 1 ) { ?>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><strong>Ordem de Depósito</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Banco</strong></td>
          <td align="left"><?php echo $Retorno->Banco; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Agência</strong></td>
          <td align="left"><?php echo $Retorno->Agencia; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Conta Corrente</strong></td>
          <td align="left"><?php echo $Retorno->ContaCorrente; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Correntista</strong></td>
          <td align="left"><?php echo $Retorno->Correntista; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>CPF CNPJ</strong></td>
          <td align="left"><?php echo $Retorno->CPFCNPJ; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Observação</strong></td>
          <td align="left"><?php echo $Retorno->ObservacaoDeposito; ?></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <?php } ?>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Lido</button></td>
      </tr>          
      <input name="IdOrdem" id="IdOrdem" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Retorno->IdOrdem; ?>" />
      <input name="IdUnicoop" id="IdUnicoop" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $IdUnicoop; ?>" />
      <input name="Data" id="Data" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Retorno->Data; ?>" />
    </table>
```

Comment: Foque no problema: JavaScript. Esta linha `data: "IdOrdem=IdOrdem&..."` parece nem ser uma sintaxe válida. Reveja se está correta. E quem deveriam ser `IdOrdem`, `IdUnicoop` e `Data`? Por quê `Data` é definido como `$("#IdUnicoop")`? São a mesma coisa?

Comment: Só há 1 elemento com ID `#IdOrdem` na página toda?

Comment: Não, como mostrado na imagem acima, são vários registros e cada registro tem a sua IdOrdem, IdUnicop e Data.

Comment: Editei minha resposta colocando um modo de pegar as informações necessárias e enviar para o php. Espero que ajude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como os dados não são únicos mude os 'ids' para 'classes'.

Tive um caso parecido e peguei da seguinte maneira.

No onclick do botão, coloquei uma função passando o botão mesmo. No seu caso seria. Ex.:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="suaFuncao($('this'))">Lido</button>
```

na função js:

```
function suaFuncao(botao) {

var idOrdem = botao.closest("table")
                           .find(".IdOrdem") 
                           .val(); //lembrando de mudar o id para class IdOrdem

var idUnicoop= botao.closest("table")
                           .find(".IdUnicoop") 
                           .val(); //lembrando de mudar o id para class 

var data = botao.closest("table")
                           .find(".data") 
                           .val(); //lembrando de mudar o id para class 

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'pUpOrdemPagamento.php',
        data:{ idOrdem = idOrdem
             , idUnicoop = idUnicoop
             , data = data },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: 
            //seu código
        ,success: 
            //seu código
        ,error: 
            //seu código
    });
}
```

No php, normal...

```
$_POST['idOrdem']
$_POST['idUnicoop']
$_POST['data']
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode usar o mesmo id para mais de um elemento, como a tabela esta dentro de um loop faça algo como por exemplo:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo "<div id='elemento".$i."'></div>";
    echo "<button onclick=funcao($i)></button>";
}
```

Isso não responde a sua pergunta de forma direta mas talvez ajude.